# How to encrypt data using public key under iOS

Tags: ios, ssl, encryption

I'm pretty new with security topic and I have question about it. I create application under iOS. I need to connect with some server via HTTP and then get its public key (SSL certificate). Then I need to use this public key to encrypt some of data and send them to the same server. My problem is I have no idea how to do that. Can anyone explain to me how can I obtain the public key under iOS and then use it to encrypt data?

Comment: Are you sure that you have to implement the handshake and encrypt the data? Usually this is done by NSURLSession when sending and receiving data to a https URL for you.

Comment: Well, you are probably right :). Just like I said, I'm total noob when it comes to security. Can you explain me how you would do this in your way?

Comment: I updated my answer and added an example. Just add your own url and you should be ready to communicate via SSL.

Comment: @Eike could you paste your answer again because I cant find it anywhere :)

Comment: Maybe my fault, so I once again added my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example, when you use a https-prefixed url (https==http over ssl), NSURLSession will handle this for you. A simple GET will look like the code below.All the handshake, public key stuff will be handled for you. 
If you use post and send data to the server, the encryption will also be handled for you if a https url is used.

```
// use default session configuration
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject =  [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

// create session without a delegate, use global operation queue
NSURLSession *session =  [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

// create a data task printing the response payload to NSLog
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session  dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developer.apple.com"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
}];

// run
[dataTask resume];
```